# Magento - Category based shipping rates, is this possible?

Tags: php, magento

I have searched google and the Magento forum to no avail.

Is it possible to assign different shipping rates to each of the categories?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, but you would need to implement your own shipping plugin to do that.

[This](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module) magento wiki article will be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

As an implementation caveat, remember that products can be in multiple categories.

Answer (score 0):

It's the cop-out answer, but there are modules that allow you to assign items to groups and have shipping rates per-group.

http://www.webshopapps.com/uk/shipping/productmatrix-shipping-extension.html